What function can model a decay, whose linear slope smoothly changes around a certain x value.
am a biology student trying to find a fitting function to model the $1/f$ decay or 'aperiodic component' of a neural power spectrum.
In an (over)simplified way it can often be describes with the equation:
$$y = o - \log_{10}(x^d)$$
where $y$ is the power value in db and $x$ is the frequency in Hz.
$o$ is the offset, i.e. the power value at $x = 0$ and $d$ is the exponent that determines the slope of the spectrum. If you convert the $x$ values into log scale you get a linear function out of this:
new value for $x$-axis:
$$u = \log_{10}(x)$$
$$y = o - \log_{10}((10^u)^d)$$ which can be simplified to $y = o - d*u$
However, in a real neural power spectrum there is often a 'knee', i.e. a point on the $x$-axes around which the exponent changes (see example spectrum: power spectrum with attempts to fit a 1/f)
The only attempt to fit this change of the exponent is with the following equation:
$$y = o - np.\log_{10}(k + x^d)$$
where $k$, the 'knee' is a new parameter and $\sqrt[x]{k}$ would be the $x$ value around the knee occurs. If you convert the $x$ values into log scale again, you get:
$$y = o - \log_{10}(k + (10^u)^d)$$
which in contrast to the previous function cannot be simplified to a linear function. However, as you can can see in the example plot, this function begins flat, with a slope of $0$ and then switches to the slope determined by $d$ at around $\sqrt[x]{k}$.
The problem is, that (as visible in the example) the slope in the beginning of an actual power spectrum is not zero. The whole spectrum is more like a combination of two different (negative) slopes.
Is there a function, that would be able to model this combination more accurately than the afore mentioned? Due to a limited background in math I am lacking some imagination. I would be very thankfull for any advice.
Thanks for your time!

I edited your post and I assume $log10$ meant $\log_{10}$. Feel free to revert it back if I was wrong.

Maybe I misunderstand what you want (as your linear function is not the best approximating the data), but looking at the curve, I would simply go for a quadratic fit.
Here is a little code to show how that looks (as you did not share the data, I eyeballed it from your plot in the u and y vectors):
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

u = np.array([0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.3])
y = np.array([3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.3, 3.1, 2.8, 2.3, 2.1, 2.0, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.2, 1.1, -0.1])
X = np.vstack([np.ones_like(u), u, u*u]).T
w = np.linalg.solve(X.T.dot(X), X.T.dot(y))

plt.plot(u, y, '-', color='blue')
plt.plot(u, y[0]+u*(y[-1]-y[0])/u[-1], '-', color='orange')
plt.plot(u, w[0] + w[1]*u + w[2]*u*u, '-', color='red')
print(f'w: {w}')

This prints w: [ 3.50825992 -0.2413737  -0.54301196], and plots:

So the function $f(u) = 3.51 - 0.24u - 0.54u^2$ is more accurate than the ones you mentioned.
